# Parametrization of a spherical cap surface

Tags: solution-verification, parametrization

The problem required me to find a parametrization of the surface of the upper portion cut from the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=8$ by the plane $z=-2$.

So I used the cylindrical coordinates here. With $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, I have that

$$z=\sqrt{8-r^2}$$

for the sphere, and by putting $z=-2$ into the equation, I have got $r=2$.

Then it is possible for me to say that the parametrization is

$$\vec{r}(r,\theta)=r\cos\theta\hat{i}+r\sin\theta\hat{j}+\sqrt{8-r^2}\hat{k}$$

with $2\le r\le \sqrt{8}$ and $0\le\theta <2\pi$.

Edit: With the help of @Ted Shifrin, I am trying to use spherical coordinates:

I proposed that the parametrization be

$$(\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\sin\theta,\sqrt{8}\cos\phi)$$

with $0\le\theta <2\pi$ and $0\le\phi\le 3\pi/4$.

Is it correct?

Comment: How are you plugging $-2$ in as a value of $\sqrt{8-r^2}$?

Comment: I am basically doing this:

$\sqrt{8-r^2}=-2\implies 8-r^2=4\implies r=2$

Comment: Stop and think. Does $r=2$ really give $z=-2$?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean. It is impossible to have a negative value here. But then what should I do instead in order to consider that $z=-2$ plane in my parametrization?

Comment: You’ll need to use different coordinates?

Comment: If I use the spherical coordinate, then I will have the parametrization of the sphere to be $(\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\sin\theta,\sqrt{8}\cos\phi)$ and the parametrization of the plane to be $(2\cos\theta\tan\phi,2\sin\theta\tan\phi,2)$. Then I set up $\sqrt{8}=\frac{2}{\cos\phi}\implies \phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$. Then the parametrization would be $(\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\sin\theta,\sqrt{8}\cos\phi)$, with $0\le\phi\le \frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $0\le\theta <\frac{\pi}{2}$. But it seems that I did not include the plane $z=-2$ cutting the sphere.

Comment: Why are you parametrizing the plane? Your $\theta$ bounds are wrong, and I don’t understand why you are solving for $\phi=\pi/4$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the $\theta$ bounds should be $0\le\theta <2\pi$ here. I solve for $\phi=\pi/4$ because it affects the intersection between the sphere and the plane. So I am not sure what should I do in order to deal with the $z=-2$ plane.

Comment: The plane is $z=-2$, not $z=2$. The surface you're studying is a portion of the sphere; the plane is not part of it.

Comment: Okay so how about  $(\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sqrt{8}\sin\phi\sin\theta,\sqrt{8}\cos\phi)$ with $0\le\theta <2\pi$ and $0\le\phi\le 3\pi/4$?

Comment: What requirements are there for this parametrization? If it is to be smooth everywhere, cylindrical coordinates about the $z$ axis will not work, as they become singular at $r = 0$. I do not know if this will be an issue for your problem, When setting up charts for manifolds, it is, but for many other applications it is not. But you should be at least aware of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, It seems that cylindrical coordinates are much more complicated than spherical here since the surface consists of the region "below" the xy-plane.